# Delegate func<in T, TResult> can't access property

Tags: c#, function, delegates

i have this code

```
private static Func<fLogin,BusinessObject.User> Make = f => 
new BusinessObject.Usuario { 
Name = f.txtU.Text,
Pass = f.txtPass.Text,
};
```

So. the User class is this.

```
public class User
{
public string Name {get; set; }
public string Pass {get; set; } 
public Company Com {get; set; }
}
```

and the user has a Company
here's company

```
public class Company
{
public string CompanyName {get; set;}
}
```

so, here is the issue, when i want to access company name, gives me error

```
private static Func<fLogin,BusinessObject.User> Make = f => 
new BusinessObject.Usuario { 
Name = f.txtU.Text,
Pass = f.txtPass.Text,
Com.CompanyName = f.txtC.text
};

Com.CompanyName = f.txtC.text
```

this is not possible?

Comment: Don't you at least need to tell us what is the error?

Comment: There are two occurrences of Com.CompanyName = f.txtC.text? Are both not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason that you're getting an error on

```
Com.CompanyName = f.txtC.text
```

is that you have to set the `Com` property in the object initializer, not set the `CompanyName` property on the `Com` property.  The fix is to use a nested object initializer to set `Com` to a new `Company` with the correct `CompanyName` property:

```
private static Func<fLogin,BusinessObject.User> Make = f => 
    new BusinessObject.User
    { 
        Name = f.txtU.Text,
        Pass = f.txtPass.Text,
        Com = new Company { CompanyName = f.txtC.text },
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

You should change `Com.CompanyName = f.txtC.text` to `Com = new Company { CompanyName = f.txtC.text }`. So field should looks like:

```
  private static Func<fLogin,BusinessObject.User> Make = f => 
      new BusinessObject.User
      { 
          Name = f.txtU.Text,
          Pass = f.txtPass.Text,
          Com = new Company { CompanyName = f.txtC.text },
      };
```

In your code you try to set CompanyName property of `Com` object which is not initialized yet.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign to the property of a property in the property initializer. Also, it doesn't make sense to assign to `Com.CompanyName` without actually creating the `Company` object.

```
private static Func<fLogin,BusinessObject.User> Make = f => 
    new BusinessObject.Usuario { 
        Name = f.txtU.Text,
        Pass = f.txtPass.Text,
        Com = new Company { CompanyName = f.txtC.text }
};
```